# Converting string of text ones and zeroes into digital ones and zeroes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way, how to convert a large set of ones and zeroes (in a text form) to digital ones and zeros as file output.

The most promising approach I have tried was converting let's say a string 01001101 to a decimal number 77, then converting number 77 into encoding table character M, then writing M into new file, which will create a file with 01001101 digital bits. This awkward solution however corrupts data, because some binary values are not processed correctly. Here is the code:

This part creates text ones and zeroes from digital data file:

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bin"
$TargetFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bin" + "_clean"
$filestream = New-Object IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $SourceFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read)

$filestream.Position = 0
$bytebuffer = New-Object "Byte[]" -ArgumentList 128
[void]$filestream.Read($bytebuffer, 0, $bytebuffer.Length)
$filestream.Close()

$OnesZeroes = $bytebuffer -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {
    [System.Convert]::ToString($_,2).PadLeft(8,'0')
}
```

This part tries to convert text ones and zeroes back to digital data:

```
$RawData = $OnesZeroes | ForEach-Object {[CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint32($_,2))}

$RawData = $RawData -join ""

$OutputRAW = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $TargetFile
$filesize = (Get-Item $SourceFile).length
[void]$OutputRAW.Write($RawData, 0, $filesize)
$OutputRAW.close()
```

Somebody might be wondering, why I'm trying to perform such a strange operation. I need to statistically process and modify individual bits in a large file, where individual portions of data are not an integer number of bytes. In particular to compare bit by bit first 1150 bits to the second 1150 bits and to the third 1150 bits and so on in a set of 16x1150 bits, where whole file has about 2000 sets of 16x1150 bits. I do not know, how to process individual bits, so I made a awkward workaround by converting bits to "1" and "0" bytes first.

Comment: So what is the question? 1150 bits is 143 bytes +6 bits. How do you compare and what is the most significant bit/byte?

Comment: Is your source data a text file of 1's and 0's? "01100100111111100010..."? Or, has there been a process that converts a binary valued file into text?

Comment: @lit Yes, there is a process, that converts usual binary file into a variable with string, which contains 01100100111111100010... as it was a text file typed on numerical keyboard. Then I'm going to analyse and modify 1's and 0's and save the result, but as usual binary file, similar to source file.

Comment: The lower  (non-printable) ascii characters have a special function in a text file. Even you read/write them raw, you can't test them as a string. If you want to be able to read/verify the output, you might consider to use [base64](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) code (Google for 'powershell base64') for your project

Comment: Maybe you can use [.net BitArray class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) but I have no experience using this in PowerShell

Comment: @LotPings For a purpose of demonstration lets say, I have a 3*9 array of bits. 001001101, 001001001, 001001101. Each line should be the same, as another lines in array. On the 7th position of second line there is an error, where should be 1 instead of 0. I need to locate this error and correct the value using statistical calculation of the most often bit at the same position of each line. In reality one source file has about 2000 groups of 16*1150 bits, where each 1150 bit line should be the same within 16 lines sub array.

Comment: @LotPings Yes! You are probably right and that would be the most elegant solution. I have also accidentally found this BitArray class, while doing further research a few hours ago. However I have the same problem, that I do no know, how to use it. I have a little experience in programming, so I need a sample code, where I can edit copy-pasted blocks to build a new code. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any samples how to load binary file into BitArray or how to save edited BitArray back to file.

Answer (score 1):

According to my further research and a good tip from LotPings using .net BitArray class seems to be an universal answer for all the difficulties. After some trial and error I finally get the .net BitArray class approach working!

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bin"
$FileSize = (Get-Item $SourceFile).length
$SourceBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourceFile)
$BitArray = [System.Collections.BitArray]($SourceBytes)

$BitArray.Set(15746, 0) #Modify one bit as a test

$ByteArray = New-Object Byte[] $FileSize
$BitArray.Copyto($ByteArray,0)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($SourceFile + "_clean", $ByteArray)
```

Now I can manipulate individual bits as booleans and save the result as binary file.